# Retun 1 when requiring a files on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I just want to ask a simple but really bugging problem, let's get tot the point

Why when I writing a require in an add_filter() it returning unwanted 1 integer in the end of the text? This is the code

```
function satufu_template( $satufu_content ){
    if ( is_singular( 'satufu_projects' ) ){
        $located = locate_template('satufu-template.php');
        if ( !empty($located) ){

        } else {
            echo require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'template.php';
        }
    } else {
        return $satufu_content;
    }
}

add_filter('the_content','satufu_template');
```

This is the template file that I am requiring

```
typo<?php

echo $satufu_content;
```

this is the output

```
test
//SomeMyAwesomeContent
1
```

this is the output with var_dump() wrapper

```
test
//SomeMyAwesomeContent
int(1)
```

This is a simple 1 integer that ruin my life (well, I tried 2 days just for debugging this until I give up.

So thank you for the attention and really hope this awesome forum gonna kill this tiny bug :)

Comment: Is using `test<?php` the solution? If so, either (a) post it as an answer and accept it, or (b) delete your question.

Comment: nope it's not the answer :), it just my typo on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `echo` when you use `require`.
Simply change:

```
echo require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'template.php';
```

to:

`require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'template.php';`

Currently the "1" appears because you are echo-ing the result of the require, which is successful
(1 - true, 0 = false).

Refference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php